# Is there a way to provide a completely custom login screen with Azure AD in B2C/B2B scenario

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am trying to figure out a way to create custom login screen for Azure AD in B2B or B2C scenario. I came across [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/customize-branding) link but it does not remove the Microsoft branding in the footnote.

**How can one add a complete custom login screen with Azure AD in B2B or B2C scenario?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general B2B scenario, you cannot.
Azure AD allows limited branding (what you linked) and that's it.

There is a way to kinda achieve a custom login page, but it will not work with users who have MFA for example.
You gotta use the MS login page :)

Answer (score 1):

To add on to the answer that's already here, while the Azure AD branding capabilities (and thus what can be applied to B2B) are somewhat limited Azure AD B2C allows for full flexibility of the sign in experiences.  There's lots of [documentation for B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/) that can help you with doing so.